# How to add extra query string variable on WordPress PayPal checkout in WordPress PayPal plugin

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, paypal

on woocommerce checkout page when we select payment method paypal and checkout then i want to add these query string with url "&locale.x=fr_XC".  can anyone help me how can i do this?

I tried to add by input field hidden on page but its not working.

End result should be something like this when its redirected to paypal page

https://www.paypal.com/webapps/hermes?token=82131722KK2268711&useraction=commit&rm=2&mfid=1614275681698_4ffe1ac0aeb39&locale.x=fr_XC

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of redirecting, why not use the smart buttons in the latest [WooCommerce PayPal Checkout plugin](https://woocommerce.com/products/woocommerce-gateway-paypal-checkout/), which give an in-context experience (no redirect away)?

If you need to set the locale of the buttons that render so they match your page, the JS SDK query string parameter is `locale=fr_XC` (or _FR), but the plugin might already do that automatically or according to WP language settings.

Comment: actually we want PayPal language dynamic like whatever language  will be for checkout page.. so for example if checkout language is french then paypal should be french too..

Comment: when i add this query string &locale.x=fr_XC then its updating language correctly.. that why i need to pas this from checkout to paypal url...

Comment: PayPal will make its own determinations of the language its pages show, based on the browser settings, cookies, and user selections.